# Ralink 3070 USB WIFI card doesn't find any networks?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian

Im trying to make this card work on my Debian Lenny, but, it simple doesnt found any network. I was sure that they existed. I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.debian.org/rt2870sta#Squeeze), but it still isn't working.

The device is this:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

In `dmesg`, I have these errors:

```
[  296.590741] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, address 2
[  314.840126] usb 1-4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[  314.992827] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070
[  314.992834] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  314.992840] usb 1-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  314.992844] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Ralink
[  314.992848] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  314.993016] usb 1-4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[  315.023812] phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel'
[  315.025334] Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy1::radio
[  315.025334] Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy1::assoc
[  315.025334] Registered led device: rt2800usb-phy1::quality
[  315.053736] rt2800usb 1-4:1.0: firmware: requesting rt2870.bin
[  315.280551] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  944.578577] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1065.357743] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rt2870
[ 1065.357810] <--- rtusb exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/) which seems to support this, while this does not resolve the problem for Debian Lenny this does resolve my problem.